# Appointment issues for Schengen visa in the New York Center (VFS office)

Tags: france, schengen-visas, new-york-city, application-status, vfs-global

I'm planning to travel to France on Aug 16 for tourism (Short Stay).
The Schengen visa appointment is booked completely in the New York VFS office and the latest date I see when the appointment is available is Aug 8. Considering there is a weekend between Aug 8 and Aug 16, I'm not sure if I would get my passport back before Aug 16. I've not come across a single case where the visa was expedited. Has anyone been issued Schengen visa in 3 business days ? What should my recourse be ?

Comment: The French visa [web site](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/us) says you should allow at least 15 days between appointment and departure. If you've allowed less time than that I suspect there is no recourse. I expect your argument will be that there was no earlier appointment. The system is less than ideal, I agree.

Comment: Yes, there's no earlier appointment. I'm checking the website everyday to see if I can have an earlier date.

Comment: Your only recourse appears to be to change your travel date, and to apply earlier next time.